# is there a function in excel to find duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not finding duplicates in excel, whenever I try to, it crashes excel.
and whenever I try to open after, it takes time to load and also  it gets down slow

Comment: Use conditional formatting or countisf() function.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Conditional formatting inside home tab with highlight cells rules -> Duplicate values.
2. you can use delete duplicates inside data tab.
3. using pivot also you can find duplicates